# VS 2017 XAML Designer View not Rendering Custom/User Control in One Solution but Will in New Ones

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, wpf-controls, visual-studio-designer

I have a WPF solution which at some point the design viewer stopped properly rendering a custom control I wrote and the LiveCharts Cartesian Chart which is a user control, I believe.  To be clear, when add either these controls to a page in the XAML Designer the controls are there but invisible - i.e. not rendered.  You can select the controls and see the bounding rectangle, but you can't see the actual control.  If I run the application the controls are rendered properly and usable at run time...they just don't show up in the XAML designer view.

If I create an entirely new solution/project, then both controls show up just fine in designer view.  However, if I add a project to the solution in question, I get the same invisibility issue.

I have compared the solution/project's and I can not find any differences.  Obviously I did something to the original solution that must have caused this, but I can not figure out what or how to fix it.

Has anyone seen this or have any ideas of what to look for to fix it?

Comment: Sometimes designer process caches too much so i just kill `XDesProc.exe`, rebuild, and click reload. It helps in most cases. VS2015, though.

Comment: Ok.  I figured out why the custom and user controls are not rendering.  I changed the build configuration to target only 64 bit platforms (x64) because of some 3rd party DLL's I am p/invoking.  When I did this, the "Enable Project Code" button was disabled in XAML Designer.  If I switch back to "Any Platform" the controls render properly again.  I guess the work around will be to go back and forth on the build platform.  Would love a better answer than that though!

Comment: If your WPF part is in separate assembly, then you can set its platform to AnyCPU leaving entry assembly and p/invoke ones x64. This will allow you to keep XAML editable and your external code working.

Comment: You nailed it!  I had some of the WPF in a separate assembly - which was a poor design.  I moved all WPF back into main app and voila!  Thank you!  Please post as answer to get credit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your WPF part is in separate assembly, then you can set its platform to AnyCPU leaving entry assembly and p/invoke ones x64. This will allow you to keep XAML editable and your external code working.